# Able to get pictures from video stream of an ip webcam in local but fails in cloud function , google compute engine VM instance

Tags: opencv, google-cloud-platform, request

I have installed IP webcam in my android and video streaming. If I open the url, it's showing the live video in my web browser. I am able to successfully get pictures from a live video stream using python in my local machine. But the same code doesn't work in google compute engine VM instance and via cloud function

I tried implementing few solutions posted in SO, but none of them worked.

```
 import requests
 import numpy as np
 import cv2
 import os

 path_output_dir = 'path-folder'
 count = 6


 img_res = requests.get("http://ipaddress:8080/shot.jpg")
 img_arr = np.array(bytearray(img_res.content), dtype = np.uint8)
 img = cv2.imdecode(img_arr,-1)
 cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(path_output_dir, '%d.jpeg') % count, img)
```

Error message in cloud function:

> TimeoutError: [Errno 110] Connection timed out During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py",
>
> urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: : Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> ResponseError(cause)) urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='192.168.0.24', port=8080): Max retries exceeded with url: /shot.jpg (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out')) requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='192.168.0.24', port=8080): Max retries exceeded with url: /shot.jpg (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out'))

Comment: Is the `ipaddress` in your code a local address when you're accessing it via the android and video streaming? And/or is it whitelisting your local/home IP? The connection timing out is the primary error looks like, everything else is just failing because it can't connect to the camera.

Answer (score 0):

192.168.0.24 is an IP address in your local network. It is not visible from the outside of your local network.

You might try Port Forwarding in your router ([here is the example for Linksys](https://www.noip.com/support/knowledgebase/port-forwarding-on-a-linksys-wrt610n-router/)), so cloud instance can see your cam via your public IP.